# HTML JS PHP File chunk upload

Tags: javascript, php, html

I am working with a file chunking solution ( cant remember where I found it ) but I have modified the solution to my needs.
The issue is that although most of the time the file will upload successfully sometimes I get an error

> Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token < in JSON at position 0

I also get another error at the same time

```
( unlink(test/H2jig-6.png): Resource temporarily unavailable in ... )
```

I was hoping that you guys will be able to spot the issue in my code that is causing this problem. I think that it manages to unlink the files too early before the uploads are done and then is unable to find them.

Upload file HTML/JS

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html lang="en-US">
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <title>test upload by chunk</title>
</head>
<body>
  <input type="file" id="f" />

  <script>
  function makeid() {
  var text = "";
  var possible = "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz0123456789";

  for (var i = 0; i < 5; i++)
    text += possible.charAt(Math.floor(Math.random() * possible.length));

  return text;
}


  (function() {

var f = document.getElementById('f');

if (f.files.length)
processFile();

f.addEventListener('change', processFile, false);


function processFile(e) {
var scount = 0;
var file = f.files[0];
console.log(file);
var ext =  file.name.split('.').pop();
ext = '.'+ext;
var size = file.size;

var sliceSize = 250000;
var num_of_slices = Math.ceil(size / sliceSize);
var fileid = makeid();
var start = 0;

setTimeout(loop, 1);

function loop() {
  var end = start + sliceSize;

  if (size - end < 0) {
    end = size;
  }

  var s = slice(file, start, end);
  scount ++;
  send(s, start, end,scount,size,num_of_slices,ext,fileid);

  if (end < size) {
    start += sliceSize;
    setTimeout(loop, 1);
  }
}
}


function send(piece, start, end,scount,size,num_of_slices,ext,fileid) {
var formdata = new FormData();
var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();

xhr.open('POST', 'uploadchunk2.php', true);

formdata.append('start', start);
formdata.append('end', end);
formdata.append('file', piece);
formdata.append('scount', scount);
formdata.append('fsize', size);
formdata.append('num_of_slices', num_of_slices);
formdata.append('ext', ext);
formdata.append('fileid', fileid);
xhr.onreadystatechange = function() {
    if (this.readyState == 4 && this.status == 200) {
        var myArr = JSON.parse(this.responseText);
        console.log(myArr);
        // myFunction(myArr);
    }
};
xhr.send(formdata);
}

/**
* Formalize file.slice
*/

function slice(file, start, end) {
var slice = file.mozSlice ? file.mozSlice :
            file.webkitSlice ? file.webkitSlice :
            file.slice ? file.slice : noop;

return slice.bind(file)(start, end);
}

function noop() {

}


})();


  </script>
</body>
</html>
```

PHP upload

```
<?php


$target_path = '/test/';

$tmp_name = $_FILES['file']['tmp_name'];
$filename = $_FILES['file']['name'];
$target_file = $target_path.$filename;
$num_chunks_uploaded = $_POST['scount'];
$num_chunks_created = $_POST['num_of_slices'];
$extension = $_POST['ext'];
$file_id = $_POST['fileid'];
$file_location = 'test/';
$file_path = $file_location.$file_id.$extension;
$chunked_file_path = $file_location.$file_id.'-'.$num_chunks_uploaded.$extension;
move_uploaded_file(
    $_FILES['file']['tmp_name'],
    $chunked_file_path
);




// count amount of uploaded chunks
$chunksUploaded = 0;
for ($i=1; $i <= $num_chunks_created ; $i++) {
  if ( file_exists($file_location.$file_id.'-'.$i.$extension) ) {
       ++$chunksUploaded;
  }
}



// when this triggers - that means the chunks are uploaded
if ($chunksUploaded == $num_chunks_created) {

    /* here you can reassemble chunks together */
    for ($i = 1; $i <= $num_chunks_created; $i++) {

      $file = fopen($file_location.$file_id.'-'.$i.$extension, 'rb');
      $buff = fread($file, 2097152);
      fclose($file);

      $final = fopen($file_path, 'ab');
      $write = fwrite($final, $buff);
      fclose($final);

      unlink($file_location.$file_id.'-'.$i.$extension);
    }
}

$data = $chunksUploaded;
header('Content-Type: application/json');
echo json_encode($_POST);









 ?>
```

Comment: You should wrap this in a try/catch: `JSON.parse(this.responseText)`, and log the response text and the error in the catch block. You'll probably see that you're getting HTML (with more info on what went wrong) instead of the JSON you were expecting. Also, maybe revise your question's title and such to reflect what the actual question is, and leave the tags in the appropriate spot.

Answer (score 0):

This isn't the answer to your problem, but it solves one problem you do have in your JavaScript.

PHP requires that a MAX_FILE_SIZE field be sent with uploaded files. This field must appear before the file field in the POST variables. So you need to add:

```
formdata.append('MAX_FILE_SIZE', 1000000) // or whatever you want the max size to be
```

before the field containing the file to be sent.

Comment: Thanks , I will add this to the code but still need to find out why some of the uploads fail.

Comment: I encapsulate PHP's file upload mechanism in a class that does all of the error checking, MIME type checking, and other checks provided by PHP to ensure safety. You simply instantiate an Uploader object with the save path and allowed file types, then pass a POST file to the uploadFile() method. The usage example shown will tell you exactly what went wrong on the PHP side by throwing an Exception. https://pastebin.com/MbbCm0uS

Comment: You may want to comment out the rename() call at line 53. I rename uploaded files to their MD5 hash to prevent filename collision and use a database to manage them, but that may not be desired in your application.

Comment: Thanks for this dude.